# ping webserver and store in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to ping a server using

```
function pingDomain($domain){
    $starttime = microtime(true);
    $file      = fsockopen ($domain, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    $stoptime  = microtime(true);
    $status    = 0;

if (!$file) $status = -1;  // Site is down
else {
    fclose($file);
    $status = ($stoptime - $starttime) * 1000;
    $status = floor($status);
}
return $status;
}
```

And I'm now trying to pass that variable off to a mysql database, to record the attempts. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking for the best way to store a value from php in a mysql db/table?

Answer (score 0):

Create a table in your DB with the following columns:

- ID - INT - Auto incrementing
- duration - BIGINT
- timestamp - TIMESTAMP - set to NOW() on insert

Then, firstly, connect to the database:

```
$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'your_username_here';
$password = 'your_password_here';
$database = 'your_db';
try 
{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;charset=UTF8", $username , $password );
}

catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

then insert the row like so:

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO the_table_name (duration) VALUES (:duration)");
$query->execute(Array(":duration" => $status));
```

I think this should work just fine.